# JavaScript style.height not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I'm trying to set the height of div on my page, because my page content is dynamic. But it don't work.

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #figmenu {
        height: 50px;
    }
</style>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function HeightUp() {
        var fm = document.getElementById('figmenu');
        fm.setAttribute('style', 'height: 500px');
        // fm.style.height = '500px';
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id='cssmenu' onclick=HeightUp();>
        <input type="submit" name="change" value="First Button" id="figs"/>
        <input type="submit" name="change" value="Second Button" id="tr"/>
        <input type="submit" name="change" value="Third Button" id="fbp"/>
    </div>

    <div id='figmenu'>
        <input type="submit" name="change" value="4th Button" id="b4"/>
        <input type="submit" name="change" value="5th Button" id="b5"/>
        <input type="submit" name="change" value="6th Button" id="b6"/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/3RKvR/ (but it’s not pretty)

Comment: Prettier but not the same: [JSF](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb4jn725/)

Answer (score 6):

Your code is working, as you can see in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shryme/aenPj/)
When your code execute this line, you will see the background getting bigger:

```
fm.style.height = '500px';
```

Answer (score 1):

check whether the page has any other html element contains same id name "figmenu"

in a page there should not be two ids with a same name